# urlrewriting.net map all classic asp requests to default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriting.net

I'm using urlrewriting.net and want to add a rule to map all classic asp requests to default.aspx.

Unfortunately my attempt below just results in a redirect loop, so I must be doing something wrong.

```
    <add name="LegacyRedirect"
     virtualUrl="^~/(.*).asp"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     redirect="Application"
     destinationUrl="~/default.aspx"/>
```

Many thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I was missing $ at the end of my regular expression.

Below is what worked for me (redirects all asp requests to the site root):

```
    <add name="LegacyRedirect"
     virtualUrl="^~/([^?]*)\.asp$"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     redirect="Application"
     destinationUrl="~/"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<add name="LegacyRedirect"
     virtualUrl="^~/(.*).asp"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     redirect="Application"
     destinationUrl="~/default.aspx"
     processing="stop"
/>
```

Try that.  And put this rule before all others.  Processing = stop means once the rule has been matched, it doesn't apply any other rules.

Also,

```
destinationUrl="~/default.aspx"
```

can probably just be:

```
destinationUrl="~/"
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this also results in a redirect loop when requesting a standard page (e.g. default.aspx). It would appear that a request for an .aspx page is also matching the above rule.

Comment: @Ben, what is your default page for the directory?  Is it default.asp or default.aspx?  If the default page is the ASP one it will non stop redirect